# How to find "original papers" on some topic?

Tags: research-process

Anyone know how to find an "original paper" (the first one or the few first ones where something appears)?

Is there some particular search methodology for this?

I saw some search engines have tags such as "follow-up study". Does this imply that some search engine might know how to find the original papers?

Comment: Pick one paper from the topic, look for the oldest references that still include what you are looking for and then repeat...

Answer (score 3):

As much you deepen your read of papers on a topic, the "first papers" will be cited recurrently.

However, the first paper **candidates** could be extracted computationally. You could use [scientometrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientometrics) techniques that map most cited works, for example. The most cited works are good candidates to be considered an "original paper".

Another way is to map the history of a field using visualization techniques. You extract a relevant set of papers in a topic, and then draw citations networks. The papers on the root of the network probably are good candidates to be original papers. And not necessarily have many citations.

A good book to see these techniques is [Mapping Scientific Frontiers](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781447100515), from Chaomei Chen. The author presents an interdisciplinary view on science study, focusing on found the scientific frontiers - including finding papers that are disruptive or initiated a whole study field.